# Send XML object through HTTP to a POST REST Service

Tags: java, xml, rest, http, post

I have an EJB application which needs to send a XML object to a RESTfull service through HTTP Post. (All in the same infrastructure park)

I have seen some examples which the XML object is converted to String before send it to the service. However, I want to pass all the XML object itself. *(I suppose it's possible)*

For instance, in a web application architecture, I would do that by using RestTemplate, as follow:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
EmployeeVO result = restTemplate.postForObject( uri, newEmployee, EmployeeVO.class);
```

Now, I strictly should do the same using HttpURLConnection instead.

Someone can help me by showing some example? 
The rest service only consumes "application/XML" and returns a String.

Follow my RESTfull signature and my XML object.

**RESTFull Service**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/analytic/")
public class AnalyticController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/requestProcessor", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String analyticRequest(@RequestBody ServiceRequest serviceRequest){
        //Some code here...

        return "0";
    }

}
```

**Domain**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ServiceRequest")
public class ServiceRequest implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Method")
    private String method;

    @XmlElement(name = "Credential")
    private Credential credential;

    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }

    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public Credential getCredential() {
        return credential;
    }

    public void setCredential(Credential credential) {
        this.credential = credential;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better that you try your idea first, and if it fails ask the question again

Comment: what about using apache client?

Comment: @efekctive, I forgot to mention that, in my EJB application I do not have Spring as dependency, as well as, I cannot include that as the architecture solution was designed to avoid mixing technologies and get a spaghetti on the code. It's specially in terms of maintainability.

Comment: @Yohannes I strictly should use HttpUrlConnection (sad face)

Comment: I think you need to clarify your ideas. To send any object you use serialization (jaxb comes to mind), which turns an object into xml/json and goes in the payload. If the xml you have is in a file/string, it does not make sense to create an object to turn it into xml again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your thoughts!

I could solve my issue by doing the below code.

```
URL url = new URL("http://server:port/service_path");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(MyClass, os);
os.flush();
```